# Disable Days: 5 days after current date on Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, calendar

I have a reservation system. On my page there is a calendar where the client will choose the arrival date, but I want to limit the client's selection of date, he can only choose the 5th day from the current date and onward. 
Ex: Current date is Nov. 14, 2016 he can only select from Nov. 20, but the dates from Nov. 14-Nov.19 are disabled.

this is my current code on my calendar

```
protected void ArrivalCalendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Now)
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            e.Cell.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add days to your current date `DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)`, see below code

```
protected void ArrivalCalendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Now.AddDays(5))
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            e.Cell.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```